# What is the most general / common South American Spanish culture

Tags: windows, internationalization, cultureinfo

Our application has the language concept of Latin American Spanish and I need to select a Culture Info to use for that language file.  Microsoft has a culture for 17 different Latin American countries and I need to choose one that best represents them all.  Any input on which one that might be?

Comment: based off question title.....mexico is in north america

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Viva México!  !México es el mejor país del mundo¡

...or rather, I'd just go by population:

[http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_Latin_American_Country_is_the_world's_most_Populated_spanish-speaking_country](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_Latin_American_Country_is_the_world%27s_most_Populated_spanish-speaking_country)

(Assuming no greater knowledge of your intended market.)

I wasn't aware localizations existed beyond the `es` master category...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx

If they haven't already established some sort of hierarchy then this seems like a fairly strange feature.

Comment: Thanks,  Yes for now I took your suggestion based on population es-MX but I was also considering es-PA (Panama) based on its central location in the region.